# Problem with date() and strtotime

Tags: php

Here is what I have:

```
$str = '12-25-2009';
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($str));
```

This produces 1969-12-31 instead of 2009-12-25. If I set the $str var to 01-01-2009, I will get 2009-01-01 which is correct. Why is this happening?

Comment: Interesting. Why is it producing 1969-12-31 as output while with such an error I would expect it to return 1970-01-01. According to the documentation it should return FALSE if something goes wrong and afaik FALSE did not equal -1. I may be wrong. And nobody cares anyway :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `$str = '25-12-2009';` or `$str = '12/25/2009';`

if the format of date is day month year use dash (-) else if the format was month day year use slashes (/)

Comment: Hey Luke, using forward slashes fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`strtotime('12-25-2009')` returns `false`, which is then casted into an integer by `date`.

It seems that using dashes confuses `strtotime`. The same date, with slashes instead, works like a charm:

```
echo strtotime('12/25/2009'); // yields 1261717200
```

Comment: Thanks. Can I cast it as a string or is there another way of doing this?

Comment: @John Casting a boolean to a string won't help. `strtotime` fails to parse dates with dashes in them, so you must use another format. Maybe for simple dates `str_replace('-', '/', $str)` will do the thing.

Comment: Oh, you're right, never mind. As long as I use forward slashes in the input box, I'm good. It was the dashes that were causing me grief.

Comment: using dashes *in this form* confuses `strtotime`. `strtotime` will happily parse `YYYY-MM-DD`

Answer (score 3):

Using dashes as a delimiter, it's parsing as a european date, aka DD-MM-YYYY. 01-01-2009 is a valid date in either MM/DD/YYYY or DD-MM-YYYY but 12-25-2009 is only valid as MM-DD-YYYY which isn't really correct. The correct representation for MM/DD/YYYY is with slashes, which another poster has already indicated does indeed parse correctly.

If you use YYYY-MM-DD (ISO date format) for everything you'll be able to avoid at least some of these frustrations.