# Conditionally populate two arrays from an array of dates based on month and year

Tags: php, arrays, date, filtering

I have a script which fills one or another array based on a given month.  How can omit non-current-year dates?

```
$dates_list = [
    '09/03/2018',
    '29/03/2018',
    '17/06/2018',
    '10/07/2018',
    '28/10/2019',
    '12/02/2019',
];

$currentyear = date("Y");

$this_month = [];
$other_month = [];

foreach ($dates_list as $date)
{
    if (strstr($date, $month)) {
        array_push($this_month, $date);
    } else {
        array_push($other_month, $date);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's much better if you stored your dates in json syntax in a text field in your DB

Comment: Yes I agree, it's an old inherited system, and all aspects work a treat other than this slight problem. So to save rewriting the whole thing I thought I would ask on here

Answer (score 1):

I don't really prefer what you are doing DB wise, however to filter your array here is a script:

```
$this_year = [];
$other_years = [];

foreach ($dates_list as $date) {
    if (date('Y', strtotime($date)) == date('Y')) {
        $this_year[] = $date;
    } else {
        $other_years[] = $date;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, I agree it's not the best procedure, but it's what Ihave to work with at the moment, I tried the above and sadly did not work for me

Comment: @Tilly After you try it, what are the values in each array?

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd like to point out that your date expression are in a non-standard European style. Typical/Parsable European date format is delimited with hyphens like "27-02-1942". Because slashes are used in your dates, PHP's native datetime parsing will treat the strings as American-style -- like "02/27/1942". [This can be problematic.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3613732/2943403)

To avoid buggy behavior, the following script will not try to parse the expressions as dates, but use simple string comparisons with relation to the delimiters to ensure that the correct unit is being compared.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/5mCiq))

```
$dates_list = [
    '09/03/2018',
    '29/03/2018',
    '17/06/2018',
    '10/07/2018',
    '28/10/2019',
    '12/02/2019',
];
$currentyear = '2019'; // date("Y") of asked question
$month = '07';

$this_month = [];
$other_month = [];
foreach ($dates_list as $date) {
    if (!str_contains($date, "/$currentyear")) {
        continue;
    }
    if (str_contains($date, "/$month/")) {
        $this_month[] = $date;
    } else {
        $other_month[] = $date;
    }
}
var_dump($this_month, $other_month);
```

`$this_month` will be:

```
array(0) {
}
```

`$other_month` will be:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(10) "28/10/2019"
  [1]=>
  string(10) "12/02/2019"
}
```